# Set fullscreen mode in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios

How to set an iOS app for iPad to fullscreen programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand the question, iPad apps *are* fullscreen.

Comment: And they have been since the iPhone's introduction in 2007.

Comment: No they are **not** always in full screen as there could be status bar which does not belong to running application. If there's something around screen borders that does not belong/relate to/with app and also prevents application to use full screen width or height then application definitely is not in full screen mode, it's just maximized to use all usable space given by by underlying window manager.

Comment: @SampoSarrala Not true.  The status bar is, and always has been, an overlay that the app's UIApplication instance inserts into the view hierarchy.  Without reaching outside of the app's process, the developer has always been free to find the status bar view and, say, change its frame to the bottom of the screen.  Apple would never approve that, but it is important to understand the difference between full-screen rendering with stock overlay views vs. partial-screen rendering (only now supported in iOS 9 on iPad).

Answer (score 7):

Are you talking about the status bar which is visible? In the info.plist for your app, you can add a new entry, UIStatusBarHidden and make sure its checked. This would ensure that the status bar is hidden. You also have to make sure that your views are able to handle the additional screen real estate also.

Comment: despite it's old, your answer is wrong. He mentioned he needs to do so _programmatically_

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays (since IOS7) in order to do this you need to override a **small tiny lily** method of each UIViewController you want to do this

Swift

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
   return true;
}
```

Objective C

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Apple Doc: 
[image]

Comment: `prefersStatusBarHidden` is now a property getter and not a function, so this answer needs some adjustment.

Comment: For Swift 5 add the following line to your `ViewController` class: `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want this one:

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

just add it at your viewController's init method.
Someone else may need it. ;)

Comment: Hey down voter, please note that this answer is posted long time ago. It did works at that time, but `setWantsFullScreenLayout:` will be useless in new SDK now. I think you'd better suggest to enhance the answer rather than down vote in this case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

(other animation modes are ...Fade and ...Slide.)

Comment: Xcode 12.2 tells me `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` is deprecated - Use `[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to override var rather func,

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}
```

Comment: Use setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate to run the method again.