# Phonegap Application fullscreen through a button in html page

Tags: html, cordova, fullscreen

I have a phonegap application which starts as a normal application (not in full screen mode). I need to provide a user option to enable fullscreen in my html. How can I make my application to be in full screen on button click through javascript or Phonegap utils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a PhoneGap [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) that calls the native functionality to switch to full screen (e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182266/set-fullscreen-mode-in-ios-programmatically) for iOS).