# Enabling fullscreen using scripts in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, fullscreen

Is it possible to go into fullscreen mode using JavaScript in PhoneGap? (hiding the status bar) I know that I can pre-define it in config.xml, but I'm not sure I can change it or not. I've heard that [I will have to use plug-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757363/phonegap-application-fullscreen-through-a-button-in-html-page), but I'm not familiar with that.

I prefer solutions with JavaScript, if it is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be very short.

If you want to run you app in fullscreen mode you can do that in your config.xml file as you mentioned.

You can write you own module as mentioned aswell in java to do what you want.

As of what i know, there are no Javascript hock that you can invoke to enable fullscreen (eg hide the statusbar) in cordova.

Hope that i helped :)