# Full Screen iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fullscreen

is it possible to switch an app from non full screen to full screen?

[image]

I have this switch and I want to make that when turned on the app will hide the status bar, when turned off the app won't hide the status bar

So I've implemented this:

```
@IBAction func fsChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(fullScreenSwitch.on)
    {
        prefersStatusBarHidden()
        println("FS attivato")
    }
    else {
        prefersStatusBarHidden()
        println("FS disattivato")
    }
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if(fullScreenSwitch.on)
    {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It does work on the actual segue but not in the whole application! How can I make this for ALL the application??

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to hide statusbar?

Comment: weird, I just searched and found a ton of resources. Why not take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182266/set-fullscreen-mode-in-ios-programmatically

Comment: @MaxMacLeod thanks mate but I'm talking about Swift..

Comment: What does a non-full screen iOS app looks like?

Comment: @dasdom without the Carrier, time, battery, ecc BAR :)

Comment: Hide the statusbar. There should be code in the Apple docs about it.

Comment: it's all the same in Swift. Just take whatever ObjC method, e.g. [myRootVC doWhatever]; and change it to myRootVC.doWhatever()

Comment: I've edited my question, thanks to you now I can make something, but..! :)

Answer (score 6):

in swift 3, swift 4 you should use it

```
override open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

can't assign it like this

```
self.prefersStatusBarHidden = false
```

it will give you a error

Error: Cannot assign to property: 'prefersStatusBarHidden' is a get-only property

Answer (score 3):

just use a global variable like statusBarIsHidden to hold your desired state

then in each of your view controllers put in the function:

override func prefersStatusBarHidden () -> Bool {return statusBarIsHidden}

```
//
//  ViewController_no_status_bar.swift
//  hide the status bar
//
//  Created by Scott Yannitell on 4/30/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 ohiovr.com. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

var statusBarIsHidden = true
class ViewController_no_status_bar: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden () -> Bool {return statusBarIsHidden}

}
```

Comment: `prefersStatusBarHidden` is now a property getter and not a function, so this answer needs some adjustment.

Comment: Hi James, If you got a newer or better answer please put it in as a new answer because I no longer use swift.